# MVC5 Azure Blobs and Models

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, azure-blob-storage

Hello I have functionality to save text and image from forms to Azure SQL db  (text) and to Azure Blobs for my images. Also it's hosted in cloud in Azure and saving and uploading works fine. Running on the usual stack C# EF MVC5 Bootstrap Vanilla js and Azure Blobs Webrole etc.

I am stuck on an area I can't seem to figure out - display my view model (this is a viewmodel with two EF objects i.e. two database tables) together with the blob list (Azure blob object). Due to them not being same context types technically is the issue, but how can we combine the two and output like so:

Return View(jobsVModel + Blobs);

Here is my current working:
Model:

```
namespace client.Models
{
    public class JoinUsersandJobsModel : DbContext
    {


        public tradesusers tradesusers { get; set; }
        public jobs jobs { get; set; }
        public uploadedfiles uploadedfiles { get; set; }
        //add a blob service to our model
        //public BlobProfileImageServices _blobServices = new BlobProfileImageServices();


    }

}
```

The I have my Controller:

```
private traderEntities db = new traderEntities();
BlobProfileImageServices _blobServices = new BlobProfileImageServices();
    public ActionResult Index(string usernameCookie)
        {


            var viewModel = from u in db.tradesusers
                            join j in db.jobs on u.id equals j.jobbyuserid
                            join pic in db.uploadedfiles on j.id equals pic.ImageId
                            where u.email.Equals(usernameCookie) 
                            select new JoinUsersandJobsModel { tradesusers = u, jobs = j, uploadedfiles = pic };

            //blob container
            List<ImageVM> images;

            CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobServices.GetCloudBlobContainer();
            List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
            foreach (var blobItem in blobContainer.ListBlobs())
            {
                blobs.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());

            }

            images = blobs
               // convert an Azure blob record into an ImageVM:
               .Select(b => new ImageVM()
               {

               })
               .ToList();

            //return View(blobs);


            //return View(imageModel);

            //List<Object> allS = (from x in viewModel select (Object)x).ToList();
            //allS.AddRange((from x in blobs select (Object)x).ToList());

            return View(images);
            //return View(db.tradesusers.ToList());
        }
```

As you can see above I want to return the two objects, one of which is called 'blobs' and the second called 'viewModel' together at the same time to my view but we can see they're are two different object types! 'Return View(viewModel.ToList());' alone works, so does 'Return View(blobs);'.

My View:

```
@model IEnumerable<traderclient.Models.JoinUsersandJobsModel>
<--!@model2 List<traderclient.Models.ImageVM>-->

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Profile";
}

        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
        <head>
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
            <title>system - Client's Profile</title>
        </head>
        <body>

            <br /><br /><br /><br /><br />
            <h1>Profile</h1>


                @foreach (var item in Model)
                {

                    <div>
                        <h5> Profile pic</h5>



                        <hr />


                        <dl class="dl-horizontal">
                            <dt>
                                Pic
                            </dt>

                            <dt>

                            </dt>

                            <dd>

                                <img src="@Url.Content(@item.uploadedfiles.ImagePath+@item.uploadedfiles.ImageName)" width="250" height="250" multiple />


                            </dd>

                        </dl>
                        <p>
                            @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = @item }) |
                            @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
                        </p>
                    </div>          }



            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="table" style="width:200px;">
                            <tr>
                                <td style="width:50%"> Image </td>
                                <td style="width:25%"> Delete </td>
                            </tr>


                            <ul style="list-style-type:none; padding:0;">
                                @foreach (var item in model2)
                                {
                                    <tr>
                                        <td> <img src="@item." alt="image here is" width="100" height="100" /> </td>
                                        <td> <input type="button" id="@item." onclick="deleteImage('@item');" value="Delete" /></td>
                                    </tr>
                                }
                            </ul>
                        </table>
                    </td>
                    <td style="width:100px"></td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Again above in the View using only ONE Model definition works so i.e. the IEnumerable for the jobs or tradesusers tables or if I ONLY use the List object for the Blob image object that works too. But like the controller I cannot combine the two. As I've previously mentioned the rest of data (all data apart from the blob) all resides in the Azure SQL database. Only the images live in the Azure Blobs.

Don't forget my definition for my Blobs which resides in this project's root too as a separate class:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it in the end/provided workaround. So your answer helped a bit but not quite enough @Dai

To fix do this:
Model:

//SQL MODELs

//Filename: JoinUsersandJobsModel.cs

```
namespace client.Models
{
    public class JoinUsersandJobsModel : DbContext
    {


    public tradesusers tradesusers { get; set; }
    public jobs jobs { get; set; }
    public uploadedfiles uploadedfiles { get; set; }
    //Blob service does not need to be here


}
```

}

//FileModel - this is an additional model here to handle blob data

//Filename: FileListModel.cs

```
namespace client.Models
{
public class FileListModel
{
public FileListModel(IEnumerable<IListBlobItem> list)
{
if (list != null)
{
Files = new List<FileInfo>();
foreach (var item in list)
{
FileInfo info = FileInfo.CreateFromIListBlobItem(item);
if (info != null)
{
Files.Add(info);
}
}
}
}
public List<FileInfo> Files { get; set; }
}
public class FileInfo
{
public string FileName { get; set; }
public string URL { get; set; }
public long Size { get; set; }

public static FileInfo CreateFromIListBlobItem(IListBlobItem item)
{
if (item is CloudBlockBlob)
{
var blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;
return new FileInfo { FileName = blob.Name,
URL = blob.Uri.ToString(),
Size = blob.Properties.Length };
}
return null;
}
}
}
```

//Controller for Azure SQL

```
private traderEntities db = new traderEntities();
BlobProfileImageServices _blobServices = new BlobProfileImageServices();
    public ActionResult Index(string usernameCookie)
        {

            var viewModel = from u in db.tradesusers
                            join j in db.jobs on u.id equals j.jobbyuserid
                            where u.email.Equals(usernameCookie) 
                            select new JoinUsersandJobsModel { tradesusers = u, jobs = j, uploadedfiles = pic };

            return View(viewModel);

        }
```

//Controller for Azure Blobs

//End by throwing back a Partial and return blobs of same Action type

//and of model blobs (Blobs)

//We later embed the partial into the client

```
 public ActionResult loadMyBlob()
    {
     CloudBlobContainer blobContainer = _blobServices.GetCloudBlobContainer();
                List<string> blobs = new List<string>();
                foreach (var blobItem in blobContainer.ListBlobs())
                {
                    blobs.Add(blobItem.Uri.ToString());

                }

    return PartialView("loadMyBlob", blobs);

    }
```

//Design our Partial Strongly Typed and ref our Model for blobs

```
@model yourApp.Models.FileListModel
@{
ViewBag.Title = "File List";
}
<h2>File List</h2>

<ul>
@foreach (var item in Model.Files)
{
<li>
<a href="@item.URL">@item.FileName</a> (@item.Size bytes)
</li>
}
</ul>
@Html.ActionLink("Upload Another File", "UploadFile")
```

//Finally embed our Partial into the View of the Action - "Index" in our case

//The embed code can be placed anywhere in your View

//Action will be executed on request and blob pulled through

```
<embed src='@Url.Action("loadMyBlob", "Profile")'>
```

If any one needs help on similar setup please let me know.

Refs:
ALSO props and thanks go out to John Ciliberti where I copied his idea from his book for the FileListModel Class and how to display it in View.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't use your internal objects (be it `Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Storage.*` objects) or your own database entities) as ViewModels - you should create new ViewModel classes for each logical view component (view, partial, repeated element, etc) and populate them inside your Controller actions with data from your internal objects.

For example, if you have a View which shows a list of images, then it would be like this:

```
class ImagesController : Controller {

    public ActionResult Index() {

        List<ImageVM> images;
        if( useAzure ) {

            List<CloudStorageBlob> blobs = GetBlobs( ... );
            images = blobs
                // convert an Azure blob record into an ImageVM:
                .Select( b => new ImageVM()
                {
                    Url = b.BlobUrl
                } )
                .ToList();
        }
        else { // use local SQL

            List<MyImageEntity> dbImages = GetImagesFromDB( ... );
            images = dbImages
                // convert a database MyImageEntity into an ImageVM:
                .Select( i => new ImageVM()
                {
                    Url = i.ImageAddress
                } )
                .ToList();
        }

        return this.View( images );
    }
}
```

ViewModels:

```
public class ImageVM {
    public String Url { get; set; }
    public String TitleText { get; set; }
    public String Etc { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@model List<ImageVM>

<ul>
@foreach(ImageVM image in this.Model) {
    <li><img src="@image.Url" title="@image.TitleText" /></li>
}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Dai. Does your answer combine my SQL object and Blob object together? I think it only concentrates on the images blobs but not my SQL object. As I mentioned my text data lives in the Azure SQL DB which is separate to where my image data lives which is in the Azure Blobs. I want to combine the two in a Model or Controller, and also output them together on one View. I have added code sample to help you.

Comment: @jamawa if you're asking that question it means you haven't read my answer or don't understand it.

Comment: Must be the latter. Let's try again so in short what you're saying is have a separate Controller each with its own Model and View? If that's the case won't I have two separate Views? If that's the case then does this answer my question of having one View with two models made up of one part Azure Sql db and one part Azure blob? Please elaborate by giving a full example of both models implemented.

Comment: No, you only need a single Controller, a single ViewModel, and a single View. You just need to translate your internal Model objects (the Azure Rows and your DB Rows) into ViewModel objects which are rendered by the View. (A ViewModel is *not* the Model).

Comment: Doesn't sound like you've ever done this before since you keep giving me back explanations when all I now need is code as answers! ;-) Your answer doesn't answer my question since all you have an 'If' statement which chooses between one or either (text data or image data). Also you have not even taken into consideration my Blob Service call. You don't even notice that I said text data is from Azure SQL DB (not mages in Azure SQL DB) since I clearly stated the images live in the Azure Blob.